# Redux: async actions without modifying the store

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Is it a good idea to send http requests from redux-thunk middleware even if this http request doesn't modify the store?
Here is some code explaing what I mean:

```
export const CONFIRM_UPLOAD_REQUEST = 'CONFIRM_UPLOAD_REQUEST';
export const CONFIRM_UPLOAD_SUCCESS = 'CONFIRM_UPLOAD_SUCCESS';
export const CONFIRM_UPLOAD_FAILURE = 'CONFIRM_UPLOAD_FAILURE';

function _confirmUpload() {
  return {
    [CALL_API]: {
      types: [CONFIRM_UPLOAD_REQUEST, CONFIRM_UPLOAD_SUCCESS, CONFIRM_UPLOAD_FAILURE],
      requestMethod: 'POST',
      endpoint: `upload/confirm`
    }
  };
}

export function confirmUpload() {
  return (dispatch) => dispatch(_confirmUpload());
}
```

When I send this action, my middleware will execute *POST upload/confirm* request. It will not modify the store (so I don't have a reducer for CONFIRM_UPLOAD_SUCCESS).

The question: how bad is this approach? Must I execute http request directly (not via middleware)?

Comment: Not really sure if its good practise or not -- but you could run the function without dispatching it (as its not updating the store):

`export function confirmUpload() { /*regular http request here*/ }`

No need to return object for reducer as its not dispatching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering on my own question, yes it's bad practice because the component will be re-rendered even if its properties were not changed